# How to show floating-icon over Screen Locked?

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button, keyguard

I follow the tutorial of **AndroidHive** to create an Android Floating Widget like Facebook Chat Head. The app runs successfully and shows the floating icon. The problem occurs while the **screen locked**, the `floating-icon` disappears when the screen goes off. I recently worked on to open activity from the lock screen. The following code added before `setContentView()` work perfectly.

**But where to add this parameter in the service:**

```
    Window wind = this.getWindow();
    wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Any idea to show floating icon on screen locked?

Comment: Did you get the answer? I also want to implement that on my app.